# SQL Server - could not find the existing data using the exact text

Tags: sql-server

I have a weird encounter when I use select query in SQL server

I am trying to search for "Malaysia Time" in a table but couldn't find it although its already in the table. picture sample:

Data existing in database:

[image]

Can't find data when filtered with exact text

[image]

When I tried to paste it in notepad ++ and used the search all in the current document, it also couldn't find the text as given in picture

only found the first and second "Malaysia Time" but could not see the third "Malaysia Time" in the picture

[image]

only found the third Malaysia Time but could not find the first and second "Malaysia Time"

[image]

does somebody encounter this? How can this be resolved?

BTW, the first and second "Malaysia Time" is from the Google Timezone API and the third one is the text from the SQL server database

Comment: I've tried that but, when I encode those to ascii, it just look completely similar and no weird characters that showed..

Comment: Thank you, I think I saw now the weird character from the third Malaysia Time. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't paste a picture in the comment so I'll just put here my thanks you for your help

its so weird. I convert the texts to UTF-8 and saw the space in third "Malaysia Time" become a weird character now..

[image]

Comment: Pretty much always the answer with these sorts of questions: a strange non-printable character, or a character that looks like another